# ParaView: display director

Tags: paraview

I'm trying to display liquid crystal directors using ParaView. The director is a spin-2 field that should look like a headless vector, centred in the middle, like the cylinders in this picture:
https://pbs.twimg.com/media/C8fj1bWXoAEFy5R.png

I know how to make an arrow filter, like this other picture, but it's not what I want:
https://summerofhpc.prace-ri.eu/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/arrows.png

I can't find the filter that will do what I need. Could you please tell me if I need to create a custom filter or if there's a quicker way to obtain this result within ParaView?

My data are expressed as 3D vectors within a VTU (unstructured grid) file.

Thanks in advance and sorry for the newbie question!

Comment: I assume that the "arrow filter" is actually the Glyph filter using the default value for Glyph Type. Have you tried other Glyph Types? There is a Cylinder glyph, but I think you will find it much easier to modify the parameters if you use a Line glyph and then send the result to a Tube filter.

Comment: The cylinder glyph didn't work for me, but your solution of using a Line glyph and send the result to a Tube filter did exactly what I was looking for! Please make it answer so that I can mark it. Thanks a lot!